# Advancing RxJava's TestScheduler for a blocking call to delay()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

Using RxJava2 I have a class that bridges the reactive to the non-reactive world. In this class, there is a **overridden method, that returns some value after a potentially long processing**. This processing is **embedded to the reactive world** using `Single.create(emitter -> ...)`.

*The processing time is crucial for me, as there is a difference regarding the business logic, whether a second subscriber appears while the processing is running or after it has been completed (or cancelled).*

Now I'm into testing this class - therefore, I need the **long processing time to be virtual only**. RxJava's `TestScheduler` to the rescue!

To create a test-implementation for that bridging base-class, that emulates the delay, I need a blocking (!) call on the TestScheduler, where the advancing in time is triggered on a separate thread. (Otherwise the advancing in time would never be triggered.)

My problem is, that **I need the advancing in time to be delayed at least until the 'expensive computation' is blocking** - otherwise time get's changed *before* the delay-operator gets active and therefore, it waits until another advancing which will never happen.

I can solve this by calling `Thread.sleep(100)` before the call to advance in time - but that seems a little ugly to me... How long to wait? For multiple tests, that time adds up, but failing because of timing problems... ugh.

*Any idea how to test this situation in a hopefully more clean way?* **Thanks!**

```
import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestSchedulerBlocking {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

        // the task - in reality, this is a task with a overridden method returning some value, where I need to delay the return in a test-implementation.
        Single<String> single = Single.create(emitter -> {

            System.out.println("emitting on " + Thread.currentThread() + " ...");

            // This is the core of my problem: I need some way to test a (synchronous) delay before the next line executes
            // (e.g. method returns, or, in another case, an exception is thrown).
            // Thread.sleep(<delay>) would be straight forward, but I want to use TestScheduler's magic time-advancing in my tests...
            // Using the usual non-blocking methods of RX, everything works fine for testing using the testScheduler, but here it doesn't help.
            // Here I need to synchronize it somehow, that the advancing in time is done *after* this call is blocking.
            // I tried a CountDownLatch in doOnSubscribe, but apparently, that's executed too early for me - I'd need doAfterSubscribe or so...
            // Final word on architecture: I'm dealing with the bridging of the reactive to the non-reactive world, so I can't just change the architecture.
            Completable.complete()
                       .delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
                       .doOnSubscribe(__ -> System.out.println("onSubcribe: completable"))
                       .blockingAwait();

            System.out.println("<< blocking released >>");

            // this has to be delayed! Might be, for example, a return or an exception in real world.
            emitter.onSuccess("FooBar!");

        });


        System.out.println("running the task ...");
        TestObserver<String> testObserver = single.doOnSubscribe(__ -> System.out.println("onSubcribe: single"))
                                                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                                  .test();

        // Without this sleep, the advancing in testScheduler's time is done *before* the doIt() is executed,
        // and therefore the blockingAwait() blocks until infinity...
        System.out.println("---SLEEPING---");
        Thread.sleep(100);

        // virtually advance the blocking delay 
        System.out.println("---advancing time---");
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // wait for the task to complete
        System.out.println("await...");
        testObserver.await();

        // assertions on task results, etc.
        System.out.println("finished. now do some testing... values (expected [FooBar!]): " + testObserver.values());

    }

}
```

*[Note: I asked this question in a more complex and verbose way on yesterday - but as it was too hot in my office and it had several flaws and mistakes. Therefore I've deleted it and now it's more condensed to the real problem.]*

Comment: Makes no sense. What else is the test scheduler driving? You don't have to wait at all and let the single body simply follow through immediately.

Comment: @akarnokd I'd be glad if you were right - but unfortunately, if I remove the sleep, I get this output: 

running the task ...
---SLEEPING---
---advancing time---
await...
onSubcribe: single
emitting on Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main] ...
onSubcribe: completable

As you can see, the timetravel is done way before the blocking thread is ready for it.

The scheduler doesn't do anything else, it's just this short program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a long-running service and you want to be able to test subscriptions to services that will be affected by your long-running service. I have approached this in the following way.

Define your service as you have, using a `TestScheduler` to control its advancement in time. Then define your test stimuli using the same test scheduler.

This emulates the blocking entity. Don't use "block".

```
Single<String> single = Observable.timer( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler )
                          .doOnNext( _l -> {} )
                          .map( _l -> "FooBar!" )
                          .take( 1 )
                          .toSingle();

// set up asynchronous operations
Observable.timer( 1_500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler )
  .subscribe( _l -> performTestAction1() );
Observable.timer( 1_900, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler )
  .subscribe( _l -> performTestAction2() );
Observable.timer( 3_100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler )
  .subscribe( _l -> performTestAction3() );
System.out.println("running the task ...");
TestObserver<String> testObserver = single.doOnSubscribe(__ -> System.out.println("onSubcribe: single"))
                                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                            .test();

// virtually advance the blocking delay 
System.out.println("---advancing time---");
testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You should see that `performTestAction1()` occurs, then `performTestAction2()` then the `single` finishes, then `performTestAction3()`. All of that is driven by the test scheduler.